# Idea to solve $3^{\phi(n)}\equiv 4 \pmod{11}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, special-functions, congruences

I have to solve $3^{\phi(n)}\equiv 4 \pmod{11}$, where $\phi(n)$ is Euler's function. I have no idea after this observation: $\phi(n)\equiv 4\pmod{5}$.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you supposed to find all positive integers $n$ that solve this?

Comment: Use Discrete Logarithm

Comment: Of course, $n = 5$ works, as would $n = 10$.

Comment: Yes I want to find all positive integers.

Comment: Works also $n=8$ and $n=12$; but I'm looking for a general idea, maybe elementary, because I dont't know the discrete logarithm.

Comment: Are you sure that you did not make an error when copying the question from your source to here?

Comment: No why? However this is an interesting problem.

Comment: Are you sure that you did not make an error when copying the question from your source ? Maybe the 11 in the modulus was an $n$ instead? You correctly used discrete logarithms when you reduced your original question to $\phi(n)\equiv 4\pmod{5}$. But using the standard formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) for $\phi(n)$ there is nothing that would indicate that the set of such $n$ is any easier to describe than the formula itself. Obviously, $25 \nmid n$ and $p \nmid n$ for any prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 5$, but every other prime seems possible as prime factor for $n$.

Comment: No error. The text ask for $0 \le n\le10$, but this is trivially. I want to discover some proprieties, if they exists.